# S3 with boto, encrypt at rest

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, boto

We're trying to have a fully encrypted bucket in AWS.

We have a key, `key = "arn:aws:kms:*****"`, a bucketName, `bucketName = "MyUniqueBucket"` and some json I want to upload & encrypt at rest: `payload = { "foo": "bar" }`

The encryption encforce policy:

```
policy = {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
     "Effect": "Deny",
     "Principal": "*",
     "Action": "s3:PutObject",
     "Resource": ("arn:aws:s3:::%s/*") % bucketName,
     "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
           "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption":"aws:kms"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now with `boto` we connect to `eu-west-1`:

```
def get_bucket():
  conn = s3.connect_to_region("eu-west-1")
  try:
    return conn.get_bucket(bucketName)
  except S3ResponseError:
    return conn.create_bucket(bucketName, location=Location.EU)
```

With the bucket we now want to set that policy:

```
bucket = get_bucket()
bucket.set_policy(json.dumps(policy))
```

Now next up I want to upload a file and encrypt it with my security key (to enable rotation, as the default master key doesn't allow that).

```
headers = {
  "x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": key,
  "x-amz-server-side-encryption" : "aws:kms"
}

bucketKey = Key(bucket, "fileName.json")
bucketKey.set_metadata("Content-Type", "application/json")
bucketKey.set_contents_from_string(json.dumps(payload), headers = headers)
```

However it raises an error:

```
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

What I've checked:

I have rights to use the key
I am connected with v4 signature
I can upload in a bucket without encryption
I can upload with headers set for encryption without my own custom key (i.e. use the default key) (notice that gives the MD5 vs ETAG problem).

**But I must be doing something wrong with passing the key because it doesn't matter whether it's disabled or not. It still gives the signature error**

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but I hit the same issue and found this:

https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2921

There are actually two issues with SSE-KMS support in boto.
Quoting github's [comment by tpodowd](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3032):

> Boto calculated a incorrect signature for requests containing similar
> headers as it sorted the headers not by the header name but by the
> complete header.
>
> An example is the multipart upload part copy with range api. Boto
> calculates its signature using this order because - sorts before :
>
> > x-amz-copy-source-range:bytes=5-15
> > x-amz-copy-source:multipart-1426209034/source
>
> The order is incorrect and should be the other way around.

Even after patching boto code still does not work, due to md5 signature mismatch.
Again qoute, this time from user hoppinghol (link can be found in the discussion thread under the pull request referenced above):

> Now that v4 signatures are fixed, when the KMS encryption headers are also set
> on an S3 upload, the md5 checksum won't match, just like sse-c uploads. This
> adds the header check to skip the md5 check the same way sse-c uploads do.

Neither of the changes have been merged into boto master branch yet. I had to monkey patch boto library (I know it's not the best idea, but it's just a check if the changes help anyhow) and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
s3.Bucket(event['bucket']).put_object(
                            Key=event['key'],
                            Body=event['body'],
                            ServerSideEncryption='AES256'
)
```

Uses the default AWS S3 key. If S3 gets hacked, your files are encrypted, but anybody who has access to that file or bucket can read it.